# Is asking for comments on a finished piece of code a permissible question?

Tags: discussion, comments, asking-questions

I want to learn to use `Tikz` properly. I've already created a number of pictures with it, thanks in large part to the help I received from fellow `tex.stackexchange` users. Thus I'm able to use some of the tools reasonably well, but I have a certain amount of (I think very basic) confusion.

Would a question along the lines of

> I want to draw a picture of a `****` using Tikz. Here's my code. Would you please comment on it, and point out perceived flaws, such as inefficiencies, misused/improperly used commands? Also, I could have used command `xxx` instead of command `yyy`. Which option is best, and why?

I ask this question because I find myself regularly correcting mistakes I've made for months even years in LaTeX by randomly browsing questions on here, and I think I wouldn't have accumulated so many bad habits, had I had someone take a look at the ''finished product'' from time to time.

Comment: There's a [Code review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: For sure comments might not be a good place for a _NEW_ question. Although I have no exact idea, May be for a _few_ Q's on tex.sx with [code-review](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-review) tag would OK since those Q's mostly benefit to OP. Have a look at related Q [Tagging “Please improve my code” posts](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3541/15717).

Comment: We've had some discussion about this previously: [Should there be a code-review forum?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/706)

Answer (score 13):

Instead formulate your confusion that apparently made you uncomfortable into smaller pieces and throw it to our TikZ lions and PSTricks piranha (animals are in alphabetical order don't bother :P)

In other words, instead of *am I doing wrong?* questions,  convert them into *why do I do this? shouldn't it be happening such and such* etc. questions with simplified versions. Then when you get enough confidence about those pieces, you can try to combine them or at least mention your intention in the question so that people can leave some room for extensions.

Asking many questions one after another is not a rare thing. We can in fact estimate the graduation date of some users just by their question frequency.

Otherwise I agree Code Review is a better place.

Comment: What do you mean by "graduation date"? :-)

Comment: I think percusse means that someone keeps asking lots of questions, and after a few years the questions suddenly stop.  Conclusion: the asker was a student.  The student now graduated, and is living LaTeX-free :)